# SnapShot of Google Map in Android not Working

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

The latest release (12) of GooglePlayServices has documentation (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/releases#august_2013) to screen capture maps.  Here is the code I tried and I am still getting a black screen:

```
public void captureMapScreen() {
    SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            bitmap = snapshot;
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("/mnt/sdcard/" + "MyMapScreen" +
                                                            System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                // above "/mnt ..... png" => is a storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image you can
                // customize as per your Requirement

                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    GoogleMap googleMap = getMap();
    googleMap.snapshot(callback);
}
```

[image]

Comment: In Java it is considered good practice to name methods camelCase to avoid confusion. So where is your PascalCasedMethod called?

Comment: That was a typo...I do use camelCase not Pascal.  I have updated. But really?  This has nothing to do with the functionality of my Java.  I still have no map.

Comment: so .png file gets created, but it is black?